# substring help in c#

Tags: c#

I have string qty__c which may or may not have a decimal point
The code below gives me a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.

```
qty__c = qty__c.Substring(0, qty__c.IndexOf("."));
```

How do i cater to if there is no "."?

Thanks

Comment: I think `qty__c` is a really bad name for a variable =)

Comment: @Jens: That's why I've changed it to "quantity" in my answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is just to test it separately:

```
int dotIndex = quantity.IndexOf('.');
if (dotIndex != -1)
{
    quantity = quantity.Substring(0, dotIndex);
}
```

There are alternatives though... for example if you *really* wanted to do it in a single statement, you could either use a conditional operator above, or:

```
quantity = quantity.Split('.')[0];
```

or slightly more efficiently:

```
// C# 4 version
quantity = quantity.Split(new[] {'.'}, 2)[0];

// Pre-C# 4 version
quantity = quantity.Split(new char[] {'.'}, 2)[0];
```

(The second form effectively stops splitting after finding the first dot.)

Another option would be to use regular expressions.

On the whole, I think the first approach is the most sensible though. If you find you need to do this often, consider writing a method to encapsulate it:

```
// TODO: Think of a better name :)
public static string SubstringBeforeFirst(string text, string delimiter)
{
    int index = text.IndexOf(delimiter);
    return index == -1 ? text : text.Substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: quantity = quantity.Split(new[] {'.'}, 2)[0];
i get a type expected  and syntax error ) expected

Comment: @Prady: It's valid C# 4 - are you using C# 3 (i.e. VS 2008) instead? I'll edit with a C# 3 version...

Comment: i am on vs2005.. I know pretty old version :(

Comment: @Prady: Fair enough... well, the second version should work for you, anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

You just have to test if `qty__c` have a point in it before calling `Substring` :

```
var pointPos = qty__c.IndexOf('.');
if (pointPos != -1)
{
  qty__c = qty__c.Substring(0, pointPos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IndexOf` method on that string. If returned value is -1, there is no character that was searched.

```
int index = mystring.IndexOf('.');
```

In your code, you are not checking the returned value of `IndexOf`. In the case where '.' is not present in the string, an exception will be thrown because `SubString` has been passed -1 as second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var indexofstring=quantity.Indexof('.');
if(indexofstring!=-1)
{
quantity=quantity.SubString(0,indexofstring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the decimal point in a number, which is at offset 3 both in
'123.456' and '123', then one solution is

var index = (mystring & ".").IndexOf(".")

(Sorry about the VB, I'm not sure of C# syntax)